# How to always let rsync continue when (permission denied) error occurs

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync

The following error happened with a rsync task.

> rsync: send_files failed to open "/home/user/scripts/@eaDir/script.js@SynoEAStream": Permission denied (13)
>   rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]

I cannot tell whether it **stopped** the process or whether only the file was **skipped**.
I would like to let rsync **continue in any case** and just **output the error** protocol. Is this possible?

Comment: rsync will continue to execute if a permission denied error is encountered.  The code 23 error you're getting is just a summary report that errors were encountered

Comment: Is there any documentation for the behavior you could refer to?

Comment: I can't find anything in the official rsync documentation, just a few forum posts (and personal experience) that confirm this functionality.  The reason why there are 2 errors (`send_files failed` and `some files/attrs...`) is because the first one is the error for that file that gave a permission denied error, the second one is just a summary error saying that some files failed to copy (because running this in the command line it can be extremely easy for the actual error to go off of the screen).

Comment: OK. Please add a full answer so I can grant you the answer flag and close the question.